# SQL command doesn't return rows

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have a SQL command which I know data exists with the criteria, but when I run the query it doesn't return rows:

**SQL:**

```
SELECT `USER_ID`, `CAR_ID`, `AD_ID`, `BRAND`, `MODEL`
, `YEAR`, `PRICE`, `MILEAGE`, `GEARBOX`, `STATUS`, `COLOR_IN`, `COLOR_OUT`
, `BODY`, `FUEL`, `ABOUT`, `MAIN_PHOTO` 
FROM (`ads`, `cars`, `ad_extras`) 
WHERE `ads`.`USER_ID` = '2'
```

What should I do?

**EDIT:**

When I do `SELECT *` it also doesn't return data.

when I select from 2 tables it retaurns data. So I can't select from 3 tables right?

Comment: [SELECT is not broken](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2008/03/the-first-rule-of-programming-its-always-your-fault.html). It's far more likely to be your code. If you have no data returned by the SELECT statement then there is no data that matches your WHERE clause. If this is truely the case then please post sample data that we can run this SQL statement against to test it.

Comment: @Ben, I run this query on the db server without any other language.

Comment: I understand, however, you're assuming that the most basic functionality of the database has a catastrophic bug. Isn't it more likely that the data just doesn't exist? Although re-looking at your code do you mean that the query never finishes running?

Comment: What should you do?  Start with, select count(*) from ads where user_id = 2.

Comment: How much data is there in the tables? You are joining three tables without any relations, so you would get a result where each record from `cars` is paired with every record from `ad_extras`. That might be a result that is too large for the server to complete.

Comment: Join them after select.

Comment: @DanBracuk, it returns data. 1 record.

Comment: make sure all your columns that you select are exists and also user_id is an integer type so do not use quotes... use 
WHERE ads.USER_ID=2

Comment: @Ben, when I select from 2 tables it retaurns data. So I can't select from 3 tables right?

Comment: That is certainly not the case - there is no "2 table limit"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's likeky that one of your tables is empty. The result of  that is empty.You should use a query like this one

```
SELECT `USER_ID`, `CAR_ID`, `AD_ID`, `BRAND`, `MODEL`, `YEAR`, `PRICE`, `MILEAGE`, `GEARBOX`, `STATUS`, `COLOR_IN`, `COLOR_OUT`, `BODY`, `FUEL`, `ABOUT`, `MAIN_PHOTO` FROM `ads` natural left join `cars` natural left join `ad_extras` WHERE `ads`.`USER_ID` = '2'
```

*I wanted to post this like a comment but I don't have enought privilegies.*

Answer (score 0):

In order to query from 3 table it is better to use `JOIN` clause between them

or if you want to write it as it is use alias for selecting columns

e.g

```
SELECT 'ads.USER_ID', 'cars.CAR_ID', 'ads.AD_ID'
FROM ('ads', 'cars', 'ad_extras') 
WHERE 'ads'.'USER_ID' = '2'
```

with their respective table